# Physics First: Where is Science Education Today?

Tags: education

Leon Lederman, a Nobel Prize winner in Physics and former director of Fermilab was a champion in '**Physics First**', a principle in science education proposing Physics as the first course in science followed by chemistry, then biology. Makes sense right?

But I recall either in reading or discussion that there were pilot programs that tried Physics First, however the outcome was not so successful. Does anyone know where we are today with this approach? I know its not been adopted at schools in my community.

My guess is it's a very good principle, but that the bureaucrats spoiled the idea with poor planning.

Comment: My HS teachers all agreed physics -> chem -> bio made sense pedagogically, but that this was in reverse order of the amount of math required. You can teach bio without anything, you need algebra for chem, and you really should be at the calculus level for physics. So unless you also forced middle schoolers to be proficient at pre-calc, it just couldn't happen.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Leon offers example curricula for entire years of education, and you don't need algebra much less calculus to teach a useful introduction to physics (I'm doing that in our "Intro. to Physical Science" class for poets and art majors right now). They aren't going to pass the AP exam with it of course but the assumption is that they will *take* a more mathematical calculus once they get to college rather than hoping to place out. The goal is to unify, motivate and illuminate high school science much better than is done now. All that said, I've never been anywhere that has tried it.

Comment: Here's an [abstract](http://www.uvic.ca/science/physics/assets/docs/colloquia_seminars/2014-15/Redish_10_15_14.pdf) I got today for a talk on a closely related topic.

Comment: Physics first only works for kids who like physics. I know a number of very good biologists (geneticists and molecular biologists), who have a horror just thinking about a simple harmonic oscillator. As much as I would love to agree with Dr. Lederman, the truth is that not every highly capable mind likes the way physics works, so it would be a waste to turn these kids' minds away from science in general by force feeding them one of the least popular subjects. There is no reason why a kid who hates physics can't shine in chemistry or biology class. Teaching in parallel is an excellent method.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: *you really should be at the calculus level for physics* That's funny. I've spent most of the last 20 years of my professional life teaching physics without calculus, and I was under the illusion that this had been a productive use of my time.

Comment: If I were contemplating changing a high school over to physics first, my worry would not be about calculus, which is irrelevant. My worry would be about arithmetic and algebra. You can look at celery slices under a microscope without being able to add fractions or convert units. For physics, you need to understand grade-school math. Many high school freshman do not understand grade-school math. Another issue would be staffing. I suspect it's harder to hire high school teachers who can teach physics than it is to find ones who can teach biology. You'd have to hire a *lot* of physics teachers.

Comment: Does one need to apply this approach to all students learning science?  Perhaps certain students find physics easier and more enjoyable while others find that to be true of biology or chemistry.  Perhaps encouraging the former group, or students who have solid arithmetic, algebra, or even calculus skills to pursue a physics first or even a physics intensive track would work nicely?  On a more fundamental level, maybe physics first helps accomplish certain educational goals but not others, so maybe defining these goals are worth thinking about.  Sorry for being a bit tangential.

Comment: @BenCrowell By "at the calculus level" I think I mean the same as you -- not necessarily knowing calculus, but comfortable enough with solving equations and having a feel for functions' behaviors that one *could* teach them calculus at that point. In my mind calc isn't a particularly high bar (no reason it needs to come after trig for example).

Comment: Lot's of good comments and discussion, but I was hoping maybe for someone to point me to a study or evaluation and how the proposal of Physics First is influencing educational policies if any. After my own experience and supported by the comments of @Floris it seems to me a more integrated approach is needed for the fundamental principle to be successful. For 6-12 education, rather than segregate the disciplines of physics-chemistry-biology, it makes better sense to combine all and progress with increasing mathematical sophistication - but always focusing on physics as the foundation science.

Comment: There are a bunch of links here describing outcomes of physics-first instruction: http://www.aapt.org/Resources/physicsfirst.cfm

Comment: If you are interested in this questions of this type, you may consider joining the proposal [Science Educators.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79366/science-educators/)

Answer (score 4):

This is really not an answer to your question - just an elaborate comment, and opinion based rather than factual. I hope I will be forgiven...

The idea of breaking "science" into disciplines at an early age goes counter to the way exploration by young minds ought to work, in my mind. When I, as a four year old, was playing with a magnifying glass to burn bits of paper and occasionally ants, was I doing physics, chemistry, or biology? Answer - I was doing none of these. I was doing 
"natural science", exploring the world around me. Similarly, when I constructed an incubator for chicken eggs - was that biology, engineering, physics, environmental science? Exploration and curiousity knows no boundaries - and that exploration is what builds excitement and forms minds that can synthesize concepts to create breakthrough ideas. Instilling that "random walk through the natural world" approach can build intuition, and should come before the formalization of science into disciplines.

Interestingly, when I went to study physics in the university, there was no such course. We started in what was called "Natural Sciences" (even at that level) and took courses in a number of different branches before "majoring" in one field.

One final thought: don't blame it on "the bureaucrats". Amazing teachers always find a way, although that leaves progress only on the level of one class at a time - to make progress with an entire education system you need changes that go well beyond the bureaucracy. Small plug: ["The smartest kids in the world, and how they got that way"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451654421) . It's a book I recently saw in a store; I admit to picking it up and browsing only, but I think if you're interested in the future of education it will provide food for thought.

As I said: not really an answer. This whole Q&A probably belongs on a different SE site...

Comment: Honestly, I don't think the value judgement (implicit) in the second line is justified. It seems my personal experience is very different from yours: I never enjoyed experimenting and exploring in the sense that you describe it much at all. However, I'm very certain that I'm a physicist at heart. The main difference between you and me, it seems, is that I enjoy *only* physics, not (to any comparable extent) the other sciences, whereas your interests are broader.

Comment: I think I would've strongly benefited from a very specialized approach *early on*, with serious mathematics and physics at the forefront. I think no general statement on how things *should* be approached can be made.

Comment: @Danu - there are no doubt many people like you. I base my value judgement (I hope I made it abundantly clear that this is an opinion based answer, not fact-based) on my own experience, and on my experience raising and educating children. You have to "go where the enthusiasm takes you". The success of "Dora the explorer" as a TV show is no coincidence, I think. Which is why I think that empowering (and enabling) teachers to do what is best for their class - instead of imposing some rigid structure "from on high" - is most likely to succeed.

Comment: Leon never advocated for a discipline specific format for primary schools, only for secondary (which means starting in 6th or 7th grade in most places in the US) by which time they are already getting discipline specific instructions (again, in the US).

Comment: It is also true, though, that physics is very different in its approach to science than e.g. biology. Theoretical methods from physics simply don't work in other natural sciences because the available data is too complicated and often too sparse. One can't, for instance, not "guess" ones way mathematically trough e.g. a phylogenetic tree, whereas one can work trough most of classical mechanics on a blackboard. I don't think it's necessarily a good thing to teach students that there is a general approach to "nature". In reality each discipline has a very specific approach.

Comment: I suppose my point is to first instill wonder and point out the connectedness before becoming more rigorous and differentiated. There's nothing that will turn off 80% of a class quicker than a scary looking equation. Play first, rigor later has worked for me.

Comment: @Floris I don't think you understand what is being advocated by Dr. Lederman. No one is suggesting offering scary equations to 8th graders. A surprising amount of useful understading in physics can be gained with no more math then *"When X gets bigger Y gets smaller"* supported by the right demos and exploratory labs. Kids "get" momentum from day one in a way that they don't get force and acceleration, so they get collision experiments. They get the expansion of gasses when they are heated, so they get ideal gas behaviors in a up-versus-down level. Lederman's suggestion *is* play first.

Comment: @dmckee thanks for clarifying. I was really responding to Danu's comments - wishing for a more formal approach earlier. I'm encouraged by your description of Lederman's actual intent.